# Is it bad practice to 'go backwards' with a foreign key?

Tags: sql

I was wondering if it is bad practice to have a `file_table { id, name, status}` and a `extra_data table { id, fileId FK(file.id), otherData}`. So far all my tables go forward and I never needed to get the id of one table then do a query to get more data using an id.

Is this bad practice and if so then why?

Comment: Why do I think of Arby's when I look at your rep?

Comment: @mmyers reminds me of a television phone number (555-555-5555)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_(telephone_number) -- you'd be surprised the number of people who haven't noticed it's widespread use in movies, tv, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bad practice  In fact it is how a robust design should look.  Right now you established a 'relationship' with tables file and extra_data.  However, in order the DB is normalized you should account the cardinality of the relationship between tables. Depending on that cardinality you will know how to place the FK or maybe you ended up creating a new relationship table.  More on cardinality could be found [here](http://www.geekinterview.com/kb/cardinality.html)

Comment: Agreed, the details are too vague to specify the required cardinality. If all columns are NULL-able then they don't even have a key!

Answer (score 5):

This is perfectly fine. Your table designed as laid out, establishes that one file_table record can be associated with 0 or more extra_data records. However, one extra_data record can only be associated to one file_table record.

What do you mean by going backwards?

Comment: He means that the foreign key method says "I am a book called 'Foo'. I am on the oak bookcase.", whereas an object oriented method would say "I am the oak bookcase, I contain these books: 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'". The link is in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 3):

there is nothing wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any other way to implement of collection of items associated with some other item. What am I missing here?